# meaning & origin of "wardul"

Tags: names

What is the origin of the surname "Wardul" used in some Asian countries (Pakistan, India...)? Does the word "wardul" mean something in any language? (ex.Hindi, Sanskrit etc etc)

Answer (score 2):

"Wardul" is Arabic.

The first part "ward" means "rose" (as in the flower).

The second part "-u" was a nominative case marker (meaning the word is the subject of the sentence), but when it was borrowed into Hindustani, it lost its meaning and just became part of the word.

And the last part "l-" was actually a **pre**fix, which was supposed to attach to the next word, and it was a definite article (like "the" in english). Like "-u" it has lost its original meaning, and is now integrated into the word.

So, the whole word means "rose of ...", then  whatever comes next.

Friendly reminder that these kind of questions about origins of words are generally not welcome here, unfortunately, so the question is likely to be closed eventually.